# Trying to prevent IPv6 leaks on OpenVPN server results in no internet access

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, ipv6

I've had a working IPv4 OpenVPN server for some time now, and in order to stop IPv6 traffic on it I added an IPv6 pool to my server and pushed a route for the public IPv6 range:

```
server-ipv6 2001:db8:0:123::/64
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
```

I have then disabled IPv6 on my server by putting this line in my sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
```

Traffic going to the IPv6 pool is also blocked with ufw:

```
ufw reject from 2001:db8:0:123::/64 to any
```

My server is currently on my LAN, and I tried connecting with another machine that is also on my LAN. If I try to ping google.co.uk I get:

```
From 2001:db8:0:123::1 (2001:db8:0:123::1) icmp_seq=1 Destination unreachable: No route
```

How do I ensure that clients can fallback to IPv4 and still access the internt?

Below is my server config if it is of any help:

```
local 192.168.0.27
port 69
proto udp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.254.0
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 ipv6 bypass-dhcp"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.0.0 net_gateway"
server-ipv6 2001:db8:0:123::/64
push "route-ipv6 2000::/3"
push "explicit-exit-notify 2"
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
ping-exit 30
status openvpn-status.log
verb 0
crl-verify crl.pem
management localhost 7505
script-security 3
max-clients 100
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/server/clientCheck.sh via-env
verify-client-cert none
```

If anybody could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: btw: You should be using the IPv6 ULA range for this, not some random public IP addresses.

Comment: By "no internet access" do you mean _none_ of your programs can access dual-stack sites, or do you mean only `ping` cannot?

Comment: None, but as it turns out Daniel's suggestion of using a private range in fc00 for example has seemingly fixed the problem. I'm gonna do a bit more testing to ensure all is working as it should.

Comment: Correction: I meant fd00, but regardless- all seems to be working now.